# Pandas - How to downsample non time series pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ranges': [2,4,6,2,4,1,2,5,3,2,3,5,6,3,2,1,4,6,3,2]})
```

I would like to have a new DataFrame where the 20 values (actually 1000 in my real case) get reduced to 4 values, each being the average (or other function) of the corresponding group of 5, so in other words:

average of (2,4,6 and 2), average of (4,1,2,5) etc.

It's like downsampling and it's related to binning. I am stumped. I bet it becomes a one-liner.

Comment: "average of (2,4,6 and 2), average of (4,1,2,5) etc" will produce 5 values from 20, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can floor divide the index and `groupby` it to find the mean of each group:

```
out = df.groupby(df.index//5)['ranges'].mean()
```

Output:

```
0    3.6
1    2.6
2    3.8
3    3.2
Name: ranges, dtype: float64
```

If the number of rows is divisible by the size of each group, we can use numpy:

```
out = df['ranges'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,5).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([3.6, 2.6, 3.8, 3.2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index // 4)['ranges'].mean()
0    3.50
1    3.00
2    3.25
3    3.00
4    3.75
Name: ranges, dtype: float64
```